# What is the policy on editing old questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions

Are we allowed to make minor edits to old questions?

The edits would bump the question to the top of the home page, and since the site is not that active, these edits would drown out new content.

Answer (score 4):

You can always make *worthwhile* edits to old questions.  This happens on most SE sites all the time.

The key lies in what you consider to be *minor* edits.  It is generally accepted that editing out phrases like "Thanks" or correcting minor typos - and changing nothing else - is frowned upon.   Improving the comprehensibility, improving the tags, and other edits will always be acceptable.

This topic has been discussed at length on the main meta several times.  For example:

- [Minor edits of old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131737/236563)
- [More serial minor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168190/236563)
- [revisiting too minor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170545/236563)

These are just examples.

Comment: Just to clarify that tag edits are not considered minor edits.